# Adding Java JNI -Xcheck:jni option to run command in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface

Newbie question: my app is crashing when it enters my JNI wrapper, and I have read that the Java -Xcheck:jni flag will help to find some coding errors.   I don't know how to pass the flag to the run command in Android Studio.  I attempted putting the flag at the end of the adb command:

```
adb shell am start -n "gov.nasa.svgs/gov.nasa.svgs.StartScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -Xcheck:jni
```

but I suppose that one must specify that it is a Java flag somehow, not an adb flag.
Can anyone tell me how to pass this flag in?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can do JNI error checking using the CheckJNI Android mode, detailed in the Extended Checking section of [JNI Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#exceptions).

The adb command to enable this mode is

```
adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1
```

for a unrooted device.